# Measure the grid width

Tags: html, css

I'd like to imitate my favorite site and measure it grid arrangement:
[image]

How to measure its width of each part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some useful JS properties and methods you can use via the Developer Console. This is useful if you have a list of elements you want to get dimensions for and want to get them at different browser dimensions.

You could type/paste in the following in the browser console:

```
console.log("#content width: " + document.getElementById("content").offsetWidth)
console.log("#answers width: " + document.getElementById("answers").offsetWidth)
```

Which would provide the following results that you could copy and paste out.

```
#content width: 1600
#answers width: 728
```

There may be a way to do this with the Chrome debugging protocol as well.

Here are some JS properties and methods that may be of use:

Use `HTMLElement.offsetWidth` for width as an integer. You can also use `HTMLElement.offsetWidth` for height.

- MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth
- MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight

> The `HTMLElement.offsetWidth` read-only property returns the layout width of an element. Typically, an element's `offsetWidth` is a measurement which includes the element borders, the element horizontal padding, the element vertical scrollbar (if present, if rendered) and the element CSS width. If the element is hidden (for example, by `style.display` on the element or one of its ancestors to `"none"`), then 0 is returned.

Use `HTMLElement.getBoundingClientRect()` for fractional values:

- MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

> The `Element.getBoundingClientRect()` method returns the size of an element and its position relative to the viewport.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Google Chrome, you can see the width of every element in pixels, by opening Inspect Element (F12), and hovering over the element.

Answer (score 1):

I think following illustration will help you:

[image]